# How does a smart contract like a Safe Multisig create a signature?

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, smartcontracts, gnosis-safe

With [EIP 1271](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271) it seems relatively straightforward, have a read only method that returns a magic value, but in the [Safe contracts](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/Safe.sol), it allows a signer to be an EOA, as long as the r and s values of the ecrecover function are provided.

How does this actually work?

Looked through the Safe docs, Discord, and EIP 1271 documentation.

Comment: Safe allows signers to be an EOA and uses ethereum native's ECDSA signing and provided ecrecover function to verify the signature, but you seem to already know that, based on your question. What's exactly unclear in how it works?

Comment: How does a contract sign the transaction (provide the r and s values in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

From your added comment i think i can put 1 and 2 together and give you what i feel is the answer you're looking for.

When using safe, if you want to have a contract be a signer in a tx (providing the e and s values) you use a contract-based signature. The contract generates a message that it wants to sign, then calls the `signMessage` function of the safe contract passing the message as a parameter.

The Safe contract verifies the calling contract as an authorized signer by checking the list of authorized signers then it generates a hash of the message and sends it back to the calling contract.

It (the calling contract) then signs the hash using its private key and returns the r and s values to the Safe contract which verifies the signature and adds the calling contract as a signer to the transaction.

I don't know how well this answers your question but i hope it was clear enough for know if it wasn't. Give me your feedback.